# ASP.NET Core MVC HttpGet Handler Best Practice

Tags: http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, http-get

I am new to .NET Core and want to implement best practice throughout my code to make it cleaner and efficient. What I have so far works, but is there a better way to do this, and should it always return the view? Thanks!

My Controller:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
[Route("/Home")]
[Produces("application/json")]

public IActionResult Home()
{
  //call function that loads data
  return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> should it always return the view?

In MVC architectural pattern, we handle incoming request and response/present content through the user interface (html view page) normally, so we return `ViewResult` that renders a view to the response in controller action, but it does not mean MVC controller action can only support returning view result.

In some scenarios, for example, we integrate jquery datatables with server side processing on client side, which might need to call action that return expected json result not a view.

> call function that loads data

For data accessing functionality, you can encapsulate implementation details for generic operations and make it as custom service/separate layer, so that you can easily reuse and maintain this part of functionality.